# Defer parsing of JavaScript issue of recaptcha js

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

facing problem in defer parsing of javascript 
2 3rd party javascript is not defer

http://prntscr.com/nau390

is per gtmatrix give information ill also pass the async

http://prntscr.com/nau3kw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defer parsing of JavaScript in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29961/defer-parsing-of-javascript-in-magento)

Comment: already tried that solution,  i want slution for third party js

Comment: try using defer instead of async and check it

Comment: @raj Mohan try that but not work , is that issue of cloudfare?

Comment: So have you enabled rocket loader in cloudflare