# Magento 2 - How to defer Recaptcha

Tags: magento2.3, google-recaptcha, defer-js

I would like to add "defer" to this script line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/CdDdhZfPbLLrfYLBdThNS0-Y/recaptcha__nl.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="..."></script>
```

Does anyone know in what file I can do that?
I looked in many files but I can not find this line

We have magento 2.3

Comment: Check this link: https://dev.to/uf4no/improve-page-performance-lazy-loading-recaptcha-442o

Comment: Possible solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29961/defer-parsing-of-javascript-in-magento